# Jasper report doesn't print PDF on first page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have Title, page header and detail band in the report.

The detail band consists of a text field which can have data of any length. 
The problem is, when data exceeds the band height, the extra text is printed in second sheet as expected, but text on first sheet isn't printed.

All fields are printed in first page except the long text.

As you see in the image that first detail is shown correctly, but the bottom one which had many words wasn't displayed at all.

[image]

Below is the snippet of the detail band.

```
<detail>
        <band height="404" splitType="Immediate">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="23" y="0" width="532" height="20" uuid="5588cf7f-d3a0-4a40-95e2-6fe1e4526652"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="11" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sitevisit}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="36" y="20" width="100" height="20" uuid="e5d83698-ea4b-4680-8a4d-5a838df139f5"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Comments:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="23" y="40" width="532" height="334" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="d3678e27-3595-4a3e-b10c-84df20e68731">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.td" value="full"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{postsitevisitcomments}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
```

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Image added as requested. Thank you!

Comment: I think the cause of this behavior is that JasperReports engine calculated space of area with text and decided that there are no space for showing text. Sometimes this calculations are wrong, it depends on font. You can try to change positions/sizes of elements to have enough space for showing text